# read file and display content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I need to save some data in a file and when loading the page i want to read this file and add this data to the page. I don't know why but this assignment is useless so we can't use database nor server stuff, so i have to save and read from a **local file**.

I searched the net and found knew that it is not allowed to access files directly from **javascript** but using the **FileAPI** in HTML5 i can select a file to read.

So my question is how is this done because there are no resources about this, i simply need to 
read a file and into a string. 
Thanks,

Comment: By assignment, do you mean this is for a class? If it is, please add a `homework` label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using the File API (HTML5) including reading/writing the content of local files and some sample source code see these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader
- http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

You should be aware that not all borwser/versions support all of the above AND that access to local filesystem depends on security settings...

Comment: The html5rocks links is particularly helpful.

Comment: Great links buddy, but i'm having a problem with initializing this file and it is giving me security error, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @Ameen as I wrote any access to filesystem is prone to security settings... these you can't resolve in code - it is a setting in the client (browser)!

Comment: ok any idea how to do this in google chrome because i tried to deactivate anything i consider security and still getting the same error.

Comment: @Ameen sorry, no idea - I don't use Chrome :-(

Comment: did you test this api on other browsers? if yes i don't mind getting this to work on any browser. If not, no problem and thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Ameen since I don't know enough about the specific operations you are trying to implement this is not possible to answer except, yes - a colleague of mine used the API to read local files (working with FireFox IIRC) and it worked fine...